# Malloc not working after some calls (C, compiled with gcc for MinGW-W64 on Windows 10)

Tags: c, windows, gcc, malloc, mingw

I need to test the performance of my project on Windows.
I have an array of arrays `rede_conexoes`, and allocate each position in a loop, but after some iterations the `malloc` function doesn't work and abruptly stops my process, before I can even test the return value and shows no error message.

The code works perfectly fine on the WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) on Windows 10. To test the code natively on Windows, I installed Mingw-w64 for the gcc compiler (couldn't find a better solution, as support for OpenMP is needed).
Here is the snippet with the `malloc` function:

```c
bool **rede_conexoes = (bool**) malloc(num_PL * sizeof(bool*));
...
for(int i = 0; i < num_PL; i++){
    rede_conexoes[i] = (bool*)malloc(num_PL*sizeof(bool)); // <- Error occurs here
    if(rede_conexoes[i] == NULL) exit(1); // <- Can't get to this line after the error
    for(int j = 0; j < num_PL; j++)
        fscanf(model, "%d", (int*)&rede_conexoes[i][j]);
}
```

I don't understand how can this run with no issues on WSL but on Windows it crashes and there is no error message.
I noticed that it starts to fail when `num_PL` is greater than `2^3 = 8`, there's no problem if `num_PL` is greater than `2^15 = 32768` on Linux. I tested the .exe created by gcc on Command Prompt(cmd) and PowerShell, both with the same results.

Comment: does the file have enough numbers?

Comment: BTW, it's better if you [don't cast the result of malloc] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: `fscanf(model, "%d", (int*)&rede_conexoes[i][j]);` writes out of bounds if `sizeof(bool) < sizeof(int)` (which is true on many implementations) and also may create trap representations. And the pointer might be incorrectly aligned for `int`. You should read into an `int` variable and then assign to the array location

Comment: That `fscanf()` is badly broken; you're telling it a pointer to a `_Bool` is a pointer to an `int`. Hello undefined behavior.

Comment: Also you should post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as the problem might be heap corruption elsewhere in your program and happen to show up at this point

Comment: @Shawn it's actually writing into `malloc`'d space so that is not a problem per se  (but undefined behaviour would occur at the very end when it overflows the allocation, and it might write an invalid bit pattern for a Bool which would cause UB later when the bool is read)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you read the last number (when `i == num_PL - 1` and `j == num_PL - 1`) into `&rede_conexoes[i][j]`, you've allocated space for a `bool` (typically 1 byte), but you've asked the runtime to read in an `int` (commonly 4 or sometimes 8 bytes).  This will potentially write a few bytes past the end of the space you've allocated.  This results in Undefined Behavior, resulting in the program appearing to work, misbehaving, or crashing.

Depending on the value of `num_PL` and how your runtime handles memory management, these extra few bytes can overwrite some of the control data used by the runtime to track memory blocks.  Depending on what's been overwritten and how it is used, this can lead to the crash you're getting.

One solution, as mentioned in the comments, would be to read the integer into a local variable of type `int`, then assign that to your `bool` array.

Comment: Changed the `fscanf` to store it on a temporary variable and later assigned it to `rede_conexoes[i][j]` and it solved the problem!
I tested the sizes of `bool`, `bool*`, `int` and `int*`, the pointers use 8 bytes on Linux but 4 on Windows, whitch may be the cause of the Undefined Behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, the calling proccess are not allowed by the OS to give you all that memory.

Assuming you are working with a quadratic bidimensional (2D) array:

```
2^15 * 2^15 = 32.768 * 32.768 = 1.073.741.824 booleans!
```

If you are running this code in a 32bit architecture `sizeof(bool*) = 4`:

```
1.073.741.824 * 4 = 4.294.967.296 (4GB)
```

If you are running this code in a 64bit architecture `sizeof(bool*) = 8`:

```
1.073.741.824 * 8 = 8.589.934.592 (8GB)
```

All that memory are available to the calling proccess ?